# How to rollback changes from ".svn" directory?

Tags: eclipse, svn

ok..before you burn me alive..its not that revert option i am asking for..

I searched some text in my project directory via eclipse and in result i got files both from ".SVN" directory and "MyProject directory".
i replaced that text with new text...accidently this operation executed for ".SVN" diectory also...

but but i havn't committed my changes in SVN server...i tried revert option...but still my projects is reflecting those changes...

i tried getting nrew checkout,refresh..is there any stone that i left unturned????

Please help!!!!!

Comment: i deleted my project ans .SVN folder(hidden folder)...took new checkout...evrythng working fine now...

Answer (score 0):

Checkout a new copy of the project, and copy and paste every item from "MyProject directory" to the new copy except the .svn dirs and files. Then, commit.